# executing program in linux through samba double click from windows

Tags: samba

I have a server with local user accounts, and each user has samba access such that

`\\myserver` lets them into their home directory.

Within some given samba shared folder from linux, I have a `startvncsession.x` file that I would like it to be possible that for a user without ever having to SSH in to the linux server they can just do everything with the mouse - open a samba window - double click on some exe file - and have that result in the `vncserver` command having happened on the command line on that linux server.

Is something like this possible, if so how?

*I currently have C code causing a `dcv create-session <username>` happening but the user has to putty in and on the linux command line type `startvncsession.x` then exit putty.  Many users don't know linux and just want to make everything happen with a mouse click and not have to remember anything to type...*

Comment: It sounds like you would benefit from something like XDMCP. No Samba required. Just start the VNC Viewer on the client machine and watch as the login screen appears (or not, depending on how you've configured things).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, any script or program, although it resides on the server, will execute on the user's local computer when they access it in the way you described.

A possible workaround, building on the current process that you described (the user connecting via PuTTY, running a program, then logging out), would be to automate that process as a script that runs on the user's local computer.  One way to do this, since you already have PuTTY installed, would be to use Plink. (find docs for Plink [here](https://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink))  Plink allows you to start an SSH session and run a command, from the command line, like you could do with an SSH client on Linux.  Consider creating a batch script (.bat) with the following, changing the values of the variables as necessary:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET ssh_server=192.168.0.100
SET ssh_user=ron
SET ssh_pass=mynameisron
SET putty_path="C:\Program Files\PuTTY"
SET ssh_cmd="startvncsession.x"
%putty_path%\plink.exe -no-antispoof -ssh -pw %ssh_pass% %ssh_user%@%ssh_server% %ssh-cmd%
```

The first time you run this, you will be prompted to add the key to the cache, but subsequent runs you would not be prompted like this.

The biggest problem with this is that the user's credentials are kept within the script in plaintext.  To solve this you could just remove the password variable and argument, keeping the user name, as such:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET ssh_server=192.168.0.100
SET ssh_user=ron
SET putty_path="C:\Program Files\PuTTY"
SET ssh_cmd="startvncsession.x"
%putty_path%\plink.exe -no-antispoof -ssh %ssh_user%@%ssh_server% %ssh-cmd%
```

Running the above command would prompt the user for their password each time, or you could set up public key authentication (see linked docs above).

To make this more generic, so that any user could use it, you can remove the user variable and argument, like the following:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET ssh_server=192.168.0.100
SET putty_path="C:\Program Files\PuTTY"
SET ssh_cmd="startvncsession.x"
%putty_path%\plink.exe -no-antispoof -ssh %ssh_server% %ssh-cmd%
```

With this script, the user would be prompted for their username and password.